# What is this No thing?

Tags: definition

[image: The No]

What exactly is this *No*? Is there any other use of it other than graphs? Thank you so much. I am not trying to cram or anything it's just that I took a course online and a lot of the time it focused on concepts rather than notation. Sometimes when notation comes up I don't understand it.(seen in precal textbook)

Comment: It seems to be literally the English word "no." As in, $g(8)$ doesn't exist. There is no $g(8)$.

Comment: This No thing is Nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not your fault, this is not a notation and it's not standard at all.

I think the book is trying to tell you that $g$ is not defined at 8, by telling you that there's **no** value $g(8)$, showing with that vertical arrow where it would have been if it was defined.

Comment: Ok that makes perfect sense. Thank you. I now see that there is a mention a few pages later that 8 is outside the domain of $g$. I just didn't put those two things together.

Comment: In all honesty, it took me a little to realize the meaning, so I understand.

Comment: @AAron It's right at the top of the image actually.  "$f(g(8))$ does not exists because 8 is outside..."  But, yeah, it's not entirely obvious at first glance.

Comment: @GrahamKemp it is cut off, but that was in reference to another graph in the textbook For consistency though, they made the domain end before 8 so they could just keep using 8 as a reference point of sorts. Yeah sorry forgot to include that in the question.